# csl how to insert a line break in bibliography

Tags: newline, line-breaks, bibliography, mendeley, csl

I am close to giving up now: I am desperately trying to accomplish a supposedly simple thing:
I manage the references for my work with Mendeley. I want to format the bibliography so that I have:

```
[author]
      [title] etc.
```

means, after the  element author I would like to have a simple line break.
However, this seems to be a major problem. I came across these ways:

- https://forums.zotero.org/discussion/23193/how-to-insert-new-line-breaks-in-your-citation-style-file/
- https://forums.zotero.org/discussion/25249/citeproc-displayblock-not-working-correctly-in-rtf/

However none of the worked at all. I can't believe that it is that hard. I tried to surround the author by a `<group>` with `delimiter="&#10;"` as well, but this had not effect.

Can anyone help me or point me a direction or is this not possible at all? Can't believe that this is so hard...

Thanks a lot!

Peter

Comment: How are you generating your bibliographies? With a word processor plugin? If so, which word processor are you using, and which document format? Also consider sharing your CSL style at https://gist.github.com/ so we can recommend edits.

Comment: Actually i am using the Mendeley word-Plugin. i think it is based on citeproc.js, but not sure about that. I do not have a CSL I have just been using a standard one trying forth and back to get the line break...

Comment: Which style are you using?

Comment: I use American "Psychological Association 6th edition" as base

Answer (score 4):

Using the escaped HTML code for a line feed (`&#10;`), as described in your first link, works for me.

With the modified version of APA at https://gist.github.com/rmzelle/b9bc934521ff7c5b4fb7, which uses `<text macro="author" suffix="&#10;"/>` (and a little cleanup, like removing the hanging-indent and delimiter after the author macro), I get references like:

```
Alberty, R. A.
(2006). Thermodynamics and kinetics of the glyoxylate cycle. Biochemistry, 45(51), 15838–15843. doi:10.1021/bi061829e
```

(as tested with the Zotero reference test pane)

Answer (score 2):

I'm using pandoc-citeproc to generate HTML. The above trick doesn't work, because pandoc doesn't unescape correctly the characters: 
https://github.com/jgm/pandoc-citeproc/issues/120

Finally I resorted to CSS to accomplish the trick:

CSL:

```
<text macro="title" font-weight="bold"/>
```

CSS:

```
.citation strong {
   display: block;
}
```

This displays the title on its own line.

Answer (score 1):

At least as of 2018 (version 0.14.18) there is a supported way to do this.

You can define writer-specific raw content in a prefix, suffix, delimiter, or term by wrapping it in

```
{{<writer-name>}}<raw-content>{{/writer-name}}
```

For example, if you have a text macro "author" for listing authors and you want a newline after this for the latex and HTML writers with a ". " in other cases you can write:

```
<text macro="author" suffix=".{{latex}}\\{{/latex}}{{html}}&#10;{{/html}} "
```

Reference: "Raw Content" section in https://github.com/jgm/pandoc-citeproc/blob/master/man/pandoc-citeproc.1.md